# SVN cherry pick past changes into same branch

Tags: svn

So I got into a situation in SVN where there was some bad code, over several commits, mixed with some good commits. We wanted to get rid of bad commits, so reverted to a past revision. But now how do I get the good commits back? A merge is not working

```
Trunk - [B1 B2 G1 G2 B3 G3 B4 G4 ....]
Reverted - [G4 ....]
Need - [G1 G2 G3 G4 ....]
```

B* are bad code changesets; G* are good code changesets.

Like I said, I tried merging after the revert, to get G1, G2, G3, but the merge merely recorded the merge; no code actually came. I can manually do the changes again, but wanted to avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to *revert + get "good" revisions back*, but I would just *remove the "bad" revisions*.

Update to latest version (B1):

```
svn up
```

Use [cherry-pick reverse merge](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo) to get rid of bad revisions:

```
svn merge -c -B1 .
svn merge -c -B2 .
svn merge -c -B3 .
svn merge -c -B4 .
```

If you are satisfied with changes, check it in.

```
svn ci -m 'Reverting bad commits: B1, B2, B3, B4'
```